# rvm install 1.9.2 fails when running autoconf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

when I run

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

I get an error trying to run autoconf. This is the stacktrace:

```
kenmare:ruby-1.9.2-p0 lee$ rvm install 1.9.2-p0
/Users/lee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #extracted to /Users/lee/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0 (already extracted)
Running autoconf
Error running 'autoconf', please check /Users/lee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/autoconf.error.log
Skipping configure step, 'configure' does not exist, did autoconf not run successfully?
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #compiling 
Error running 'make ', please check /Users/lee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/make.error.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE: Sorry it was late and didn't give some obvious info. I am on a mac running 10.6.4. The autoconf log says:

```
autoconf: no input file
```

To the answer regarding make, when I run

```
which make
/usr/bin/make
```

And I have am running 1.8.7 successfully with rvm. I only receive this problem when installing 1.9.2.
Thanks again!

Comment: What operating system are you using? More information about the environment where you are trying to install Ruby 1.9.2 would be helpful. Have you installed any other rubies with RVM successfully?

Comment: It says to check the error log. What does the error log say?

Comment: He's using Mac OS. The path to his account is rooted at `/Users`, which is a Mac OS thing. Linux would be `/home`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out. The key is this line:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #extracted to /Users/lee/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0 (already extracted)
```

Apparently if there is an error during your first attempt the directory for the 1.9.2 package is not removed. (In my case, the autoconf files were not properly downloaded.) Any subsequent attempts see the directory and does not attempt to download the package again.

You need to remove the ruby-1.9.2-p0 directory. I assume this could be a problem with any version.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 21):

This happened to me because my rvm version was old

```
rvm list known
```

wasn't showing ruby 1.9.3 as one of the options for me

I did:

```
rvm get head
```

Comment: This worked for me. One added step is that you need to open up a new terminal window so all your paths are updated correctly for the new version of rvm.

Comment: This worked for me, too. @muirbot - running rvm reload is another option (rather than opening a new Terminal window).

Comment: Yep, did it for me too: 1) rvm get head, 2) rvm reload

Answer (score 4):

I just had a similar problem. In addition to what Lee did to solve, I also had to remove the corresponding ruby's tar file from .rvm/archives so it would download a fresh copy that was not corrupt/incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to upgrade RVM.  Running this in the shell took care of upgrading:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```