# Error running 'autoconf' when installing Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM

Tags: ruby, makefile, rvm, autoconf, ruby-1.9.3

I'm using a Mac OS X 10.7.4 and currently using Ruby 1.9.2. I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM but get the following error when executing `rvm install 1.9.3`:

```
Running autoconf
Error running 'autoconf', please read .../.rvm/log/ruby-    1.9.3/autoconf.log
Skipping configure step, 'configure' does not exist, did autoconf not run successfully?
ruby-1.9.3 - #compiling 
Error running 'make ', please read .../.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I found nothing useful in both `autoconf.log` and `make.log`.

I looked at similar questions but wasn't able to fix this problem. I also tried removing the `ruby-1.9.2-p0 directory` as recommended in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241971/rvm-install-1-9-2-fails-when-running-autoconf).

I could really use some help here (as well as a possible explanation for why this is happening).

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like ruby version was not detected properly, make sure you use up to date RVM:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
rvm reload
```

also specifying full version might help:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

Comment: I tried upgrading RVM as you said but received a bunch of "failed" errors. I then tried `rvm get head` as suggested by the RVM website and received this error: `error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied`. Finally, I executed `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194` and it worked; however, do you have any idea why I couldn't upgrade RVM? Thanks again!

Comment: the command to update rvm is in my answer - the installer also does update!